# How do I rebuild Octave and link in GraphicsMagick?

Tags: octave

It appears there is some discussion on this issue. Octave only allows 8-bit pixels in using imread(). I have downloaded, rebuilt and installed GraphicsMagick with configure set to use 16 bit. I have reset the path and then tried downloading the tarballs for Octave 4.0, Octave 3.8 and Octave 3.6.2. All three fail to configure imread() into the build. According to the documentation, you must rebuild GraphicsMagick from source to configure 16-bit images and from there you must rebuild Octave from source to link in the re-configured GraphicsMagicK. Latest error is: "configure: WARNING: GraphicsMagick++ library fails tests.  The imread function for reading image files will not be fully functional."

I have already run apt-cache depends octave | grep -i magick

and export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH

then used ./configure  --with-quantum-depth=32 --enable-shared --disable-static --with-magick-plus-plus=yes

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If GraphicsMagick was successfully configured/built/installed in the default location (which is /usr/local), then no other steps should be necessary for the octave configure script to find it there (since /usr/local is in the default pkg-config path). So it sounds like **that** is the step you need to revisit: you realize that `./configure --with-quantum-depth=32 --enable-shared --disable-static --with-magick-plus-plus=yes` is the command to configure GraphicsMagick, right? the way you wrote it, it sounds like you used that to configure octave.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct and I have rebuilt and installed both GraphicsMagic and Octave-3.56.3 with success according to make check. Have run gm display 'hydra.jpg' with success. I now try the command: A=imread("hydra.jpg) and get the following error:  error:   imread: invalid image file: /usr/local/lib/octave/3.6.3/oct/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/__magick_read__.oct: failed to load: libGraphicsMagick++.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
error: called from:
error:   /usr/local/share/octave/3.6.3/m/image/imread.m at line 74, column 7.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct and I have rebuilt and installed both GraphicsMagic and Octave-3.56.3 with success according to make check. Have run gm display 'hydra.jpg' with success. I now try the command: A=imread("hydra.jpg) and get the following error:  error:   imread: invalid image file: /usr/local/lib/octave/3.6.3/oct/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/__magick_read__.oct: failed to load: libGraphicsMagick++.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
error: called from:
error:   /usr/local/share/octave/3.6.3/m/image/imread.m at line 74, column 7.

Comment: According to http://wiki.octave.org/GraphicsMagick, if after the build, you get `error while loading shared libraries: libGraphicsMagick.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` you need to run `ldconfig`. For security and performance reasons, Linux maintains a cache of the shared libraries installed in "approved" locations and this command will update it.

Answer (score 0):

(I had the same problem)
This worked for me at the end.

In terminal, install

```
sudo apt-get build-dep octave
```

In synaptic, install

```
libqt4-opengl-dev
```

Then, 
download octave-4.0.0.tar.gz from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/

unzip octave-4.0.0.tar.gz to home.

```
cd octave-4.0.0
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

This worked on all the machines I tried in my laboratory.