# Octave memory allocation error after changing GM to quantum depth 16

Tags: imagemagick, image-processing, octave

I tried to increase the quantum depth of the GraphicsMagick to 16bits. I downloaded the GraphicsMagick package from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/). Here is the result for the version details and quantum depth result for `gm version`.

```
karthikeyan@karthikeyan:~$ gm version

GraphicsMagick 1.3.25 2016-09-05 Q16 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
Copyright (C) 2002-2016 GraphicsMagick Group.
Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.
See http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.
..
...
....
Configured using the command:
  ./configure  '--with-quantum-depth=16' '--enable-shared' '--disable-static' '--with-magick-plus-plus=yes'
```

So I went ahead to process images,assuming my graphicsmagick can handle 16 bits, but I am getting this error. Please help to resolve this:

```
karthikeyan@karthikeyan:~$ octave

octave:1> i = imread("/home/karthikeyan/Pictures/Wallpapers/f1376677896.jpg");
warning: your version of GraphicsMagick limits images to 8 bits per pixel
*** Error in `/usr/bin/octave-cli': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000002300dd0 ***
panic: Aborted -- stopping myself...
^C^CPress Control-C again to abort.
^Cpanic: attempted clean up apparently failed -- aborting...
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: perhaps you need to recompile octave, too?

Comment: @Jeroen - Can you please help me on how to go ahead with it if I used `apt-get` to install Octave? Is this the right way - http://askubuntu.com/questions/652004/ddg#670818 ?

Comment: see [Michael's post at the bottom](http://askubuntu.com/questions/246690/how-to-use-apt-to-get-source-code-and-then-do-separate-compile?rq=1) for an example of how to do this. You could also follow one of the others